# Treating an instance as its superclass

Tags: objective-c

A little bit of a nebbie question I'm afraid. In short, if I'd like to know if I 
make a subclass of an object, can I use an instance of the parent class to reference 
only the parent classes properties of that object? If so, can I freely go between the 
the subclass and the parent?

For instance, if I define B as a subtype of A where
 - A has method a
 - B has method b

Can I create an instance of B and then reference it as object type A

Sort of:
    B *b1;
    B *b2;
    A *a;

```
b1 = [[B alloc] init];

// Is this allowed?
a = (A *)b1;
b2= (B *)a;

// Are these valid?
[ a a];
[ b2 a];
[ b2 b];
```

(I've seen lots of discussions on general subclassing on the web, but nothing
seems to explain when I can convert between a class and its super-class)

Comment: You arent converting anything in this example.  A subclass can always be referred to by a super type pointer. And thats all youve done here.  More seriously is if you get a pointer of a super class and attempt to cast to a sub type is where problems may arise.  Yes inheritance in obj works.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is resolved at runtime; sending messages to `a` will yield the same results whether you cast it to an `A*` or not.

In other words, the casts don’t make a difference; you could have casted them to `NSString*` if you wanted, and it would still all work.

With ARC, on the other hand, you will get compile-time errors if the object doesn’t appear to respond to the message sent.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure about the first cast but I think both casts are legal. The second cast makes sense as long as the original object `b1` is of type `B`. Otherwise, sending `B` messages to `b2` would cause errors - I think there was a default implementation of a method called when a message is sent to an object for a method that is not implemented for that type.

In addition sending those 3 messages is also legal. Method `a` is public for class `A`, so objects of type `A` and `B` respond to message `a`. `b2` also responds to `b`, because it actually points to an object of type `B`.

Answer (score 0):

```
b1 = [[B alloc] init];
a = (A *)b1;
b2= (B *)a;
```

Just to summarise - You have a single object, `b1` and you are creating two references to it `a` and `b2`.

You want to know whether you can call methods of class `B` on `b2` even though it was previously an instance of class `A`?

The answer is YES, because all three objects are instances of class B. Casting from one type to another is an indicator to the compiler for how to resolve method calls.

For example - if you write:

```
id obj = b1;
```

and later try to access a property of class B by doing

```
obj.someProperty;
```

You'll get a compiler warning, but if you cast it:

```
(B *)obj.someProperty;
```

You don't get the warning, because you've provided information to the compiler.

Objective-C is a dynamic langauge. All three objects are instances of class `B`. Casting them to other classes doesn't change their class.